# Passing two values in select dropdown using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to pass two values in select dropdown.
Here is my code.

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in studyTeamObj" align="center">
        <td>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="x.Designation">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option ng-repeat="x in createStudyObj.Study_User"
                        value="{{x.Designation}}">{{x.Emp_Name}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            {{x.Emp_Id}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{x.Designation}}
        </td>
        <td class="mdrf-add-row-col">
            <i class="fa  fa-minus-circle"
               data-ng-click="deleteMem($index)"></i>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is what the data I am getting from {{createStudyObj.Study_User}}

```
[{"Emp_Name":"mdrf","Emp_Id":2,"Designation":"Research Dietitian","DesignationID":20},{"Emp_Name":"Sudha","Emp_Id":1045,"Designation":"MDRF HOD","DesignationID":16},{"Emp_Name":"kavyad","Emp_Id":1046,"Designation":"MDRF HOD","DesignationID":16},{"Emp_Name":"kavyad","Emp_Id":1047,"Designation":"MDRF HOD","DesignationID":16},{"Emp_Name":"kavyad","Emp_Id":1048,"Designation":"MDRF HOD","DesignationID":16},{"Emp_Name":"kavyad","Emp_Id":1049,"Designation":"MDRF HOD","DesignationID":16},{"Emp_Name":"fdgedd","Emp_Id":1050,"Designation":"MDRF HOD","DesignationID":16}]
```

when I click on emp name from the dropdown,it should fetch Emp_Id and Designation.But I am getting only the Designation.Plz help

Comment: can you create a plunker/fiddle if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign object to `value` instead of one property. That's way whole object bind to `ng-model` and you can filter relevant properties from that.

```
<option ng-repeat="x in createStudyObj.Study_User"value="{{x}}">{{x.Emp_Name}}
</option>
```

The downfall of this is when u access the model variable from the controller value assign as string. so you need to parse the value to object using `JSON.parse()`

`$scope.designation = JSON.parse($scope.designation)`

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
 $scope.createStudyObj = {};
 $scope.createStudyObj.Study_User = [{"Emp_Name":"mdrf","Emp_Id":2,"Designation":"Research Dietitian","DesignationID":20},{"Emp_Name":"Sudha","Emp_Id":1045,"Designation":"MDRF HOD","DesignationID":16},{"Emp_Name":"kavyad","Emp_Id":1046,"Designation":"MDRF HOD","DesignationID":16},{"Emp_Name":"kavyad","Emp_Id":1047,"Designation":"MDRF HOD","DesignationID":16},{"Emp_Name":"kavyad","Emp_Id":1048,"Designation":"MDRF HOD","DesignationID":16},{"Emp_Name":"kavyad","Emp_Id":1049,"Designation":"MDRF HOD","DesignationID":16},{"Emp_Name":"fdgedd","Emp_Id":1050,"Designation":"MDRF HOD","DesignationID":16}]


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <table>
   <tbody>
      <tr >
         <td>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="designation">
               <option value=""></option>
               <option ng-repeat="x in createStudyObj.Study_User"
                  value="{{x}}">{{x.Emp_Name}}
               </option>
            </select>
         </td>
         <td>
            {{designation}}
         </td>
         <td class="mdrf-add-row-col">
            <i class="fa  fa-minus-circle"
               data-ng-click="deleteMem($index)"></i>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

But I recommend to use `ng-options` instead of the `ng-repeat`

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
 $scope.createStudyObj = {};
 $scope.createStudyObj.Study_User = [{"Emp_Name":"mdrf","Emp_Id":2,"Designation":"Research Dietitian","DesignationID":20},{"Emp_Name":"Sudha","Emp_Id":1045,"Designation":"MDRF HOD","DesignationID":16},{"Emp_Name":"kavyad","Emp_Id":1046,"Designation":"MDRF HOD","DesignationID":16},{"Emp_Name":"kavyad","Emp_Id":1047,"Designation":"MDRF HOD","DesignationID":16},{"Emp_Name":"kavyad","Emp_Id":1048,"Designation":"MDRF HOD","DesignationID":16},{"Emp_Name":"kavyad","Emp_Id":1049,"Designation":"MDRF HOD","DesignationID":16},{"Emp_Name":"fdgedd","Emp_Id":1050,"Designation":"MDRF HOD","DesignationID":16}]


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <table>
   <tbody>
      <tr >
         <td>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="designation" ng-options="item as item.Emp_Name for item in createStudyObj.Study_User">
               <option value=""></option>
               
            </select>
         </td>
         <td>
            {{designation}}
         </td>
         <td class="mdrf-add-row-col">
            <i class="fa  fa-minus-circle"
               data-ng-click="deleteMem($index)"></i>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using ng-options instead of building your own options list.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

If you have problems with that, add those questions up top and I will update my answer.